# Firefox PDF viewer vs beamer + pgfpages

Tags: beamer, pgfpages

Consider the following MWE to be previewed in the build in PDF previewer in Firefox

```
\documentclass[handout]{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{8 on 1}[a4paper,border shrink=4mm]
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\[
\bigcup_n \sum_n
\]
\[
\underbrace{aaaaaa}_{bbb}
\]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Obervations: First of this is what I see in my FF.

[image]

Notice how the `\bigcup` and `\sum` are wrong.

Further observations:

1. If the `\underbrace` is removed, things are ok
2. if the `\pgfpagesuselayout` line is removed, everything renders ok.

The same file rendered in Chrome, displays just fine.

Is this some kind of artefact in FF?

Comment: It is an artifact of PDF.js. Request to preview in reader or open with reader outside firefox.

Comment: @percusse You can do it, but if the readers of your document won't, then it's bad :-(

Comment: @yo' Save one world at a time ;) They have a [GitHub page](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js) for bug reports etc.

Answer (score 3):

It works OK for me:

[image]

123456789ab

Comment: So it seems to be version related. Glad to hear that it is fixed in a newer version. My Ubuntu have given my FF 40.

Comment: @daleif: David has a time machine. `:)`

Comment: @PauloCereda, since when? Nightly is newer, nothing timey whimy about that.

Comment: @daleif: if I recall correctly, there's nightly, then aurora, then stable. David lives on the wibbly wobbly timey wimey Firefoxy edge thingy. `:)`